# Does it make sense to talk about $L^2$ inner product of two functions not necessarily in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, inner-products

The $L^2$-inner product of two real functions $f$ and $g$ on a measure space $X$ with respect to the measure $\mu$ is given by
$$
\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2} := \int_X fg d\mu, $$

When $f$ and $g$ are both in $L^2(X)$, $|\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2}|\leqslant \|f\|_{L^2} \|g\|_{L^2} < \infty$.

I was wondering if it makes sense to talk about $\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2}$ when $f$ and/or $g$ may not be in  $L^2(X)$? What are cases more general than $f$ and $g$  both in $L^2(X)$, when talking about  $L^2(X)$ makes sense?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Tim, there are obvious examples. Just take $g=0$ then take $f$ to be whatever you want. Or, take $f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $g=e^{-x}$ on $X=[1,\infty)$ with the usual Lebesgue measure. That said, if you want $\langle f,g\rangle$ to be finite for every $g\in L^2$ that seems like a bit more of an interesting question.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Thanks! I'd like to hear what can be said about the more interesting question if I want ⟨f,g⟩ to be finite for every $g∈L^2$?

Comment: I would suggest editing your question, or perhaps asking a new question since it appears people have already answered your question.

Comment: If you were going to ask such a new question, I would suggest asking the even more interesting question about, given $f$ measurable on $X$, what is the *minimal* subset $S$ of $L^2(X)$ for which $\langle f,g\rangle<\infty$ for all $g\in S$ implies that $f\in L^2(X)$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: The question you suggested has been posted here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328842/minimal-subset-s-of-l2x-for-which-f-g-for-all-gs-implies-that-f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does make sense. For example, if you take $f\in L^p(X)$ and $g\in L^{p'}(X)$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$, then $\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2} $ is well defined and $$\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2} <\|f\|_p\|g\|_{p'}$$

With this notation it is said the the inner product on $L^2$ induces the duality $p$ and $p'$.

Answer (score 4):

When you take $f\notin L^{2}(X)$ the problem is that you can not ensure $fg$ is integrable, but if $f\in L^{p}(X)$ then you can choose $g\in L^{q}(X)$ with $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$, then you can ensure $fg$ is integrable.