# Minimal subset $S$ of $L^2(X)$ for which $⟨f,g⟩<∞$ for all $g∈S$ implies that $f∈L^2(X)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Following is a question coming from [a comment by Alex Youcis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328592/does-it-make-sense-to-talk-about-l2-inner-product-of-two-functions-not-necess) :

> given a real-valued measurable function $f$ defined on a measure space X, what is the minimal subset $S$ of $L^2(X)$ for which $⟨f,g⟩<∞$ for all $g∈S$ implies that $f∈L^2(X)$?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Tim, see my comment on Davide's answer. I thought our co-asked question was that $S$ should not depend on $f$. The ultimate answer would be something of the form "$f\in L^2$ if and only if $\langle f,g\rangle<\infty$ for all $g$ in (BLANK) and moreover, (BLANK) is minimal (no proper subsets have this property)" Here (BLANK) should be replaced by an $f$-independent subset of $L^2(X)$. For example, test functions (assuming our measure is nice enough), etc.

Comment: What is $\langle f,g\rangle$ if $f \notin L^2$? Perhaps you want $\int |fg| d\mu <\infty$? Is there any reason to expect that there are minimal sets? If so, why should it be unique?

Comment: @Jochen, nice questions. Your first two questions are somehow related to my previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328592/does-it-make-sense-to-talk-about-l2-inner-product-of-two-functions-not-necess.

Comment: ... I will @AlexYoucis for what he thinks about your questions.